# is there any sequence container that also maintains a primary key? (c++)

Tags: c++, containers

I'm writing a application with a grid control, I use a **std::vector** to hold all user information and display it on the gui using for-loop.

The problem is when some record(with specified **user_id**) is modified, I need to update the gui. I'm using **std::find_if** to search for the target **user_id**, get the **index** of the record, then update the **index'th** row on gui.

The linear search could be expensive when data grows, so I'm looking for a container which is sequencial so that the index to the container is corresponding to the row index on gui. And it should be associative that I can quickly find the index by a **primary_key**.

I found std::unordered_map is very close to what I need, but it lacks some functionality like insert data at the middle of it, for example, there're 3 elements in the unordered_map:

```
pair<1, 1>
pair<2, 2>
pair<3, 3>
```

I want to insert a pair<100, 100> between <2, 2> and <3, 3>, so it becomes:

```
pair<1, 1>
pair<2, 2>
pair<100, 100>
pair<3, 3>
```

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert data in the middle"? This suggests you care about the order of the elements. But do you really care?

Comment: Are you actually recognizing any performance problem with your approach!?

Comment: Also, you must be sure there is a performance issue. Linear search could be faster than other approaches up to a certain data size.

Comment: If you want access with two different keys, you use two standard containers, or a third-party multi-keyed container such as [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: whatever technique you use is going to be orders of magnitude faster than the GUI processing

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post for "insert data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [boost::container::flat_map for this, or maybe flat_set<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) with a custom comparison that will make it sort your values using the user_id.

flat_* containers from boost.container library are basically std::vector disguised as associative container. The implementation is a std::vector wrapped around a std::map or std::set interface (with additional facilities). The std::vector itself is reachable so you can still go through all the elements with the same properties than with a std::vector. However this mean that when you insert or remove elements, these elements might be moved in memory, like for std::vector.

Another possibility, if you have several different kind of indices, would be to use [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: a simple code like **flat_map<int, int> m;** doesn't compile,  it complains **g:\boost\boost/intrusive/detail/has_member_function_callable_with.hpp(200) : error C2228: left of '.select_on_container_copy_construction' must have class/struct/union**,  I'm using vs2013.

Comment: @aj3423 That's because officially Boost 1.55.0 doesn't compile with VS2013. You need to apply a short patch, just search that error on svn.boost.org and apply the patch manually, I've done it easily. Or wait for the imminent 1.56 release.